# google earth 7.1 crashing after showing splash screen

Tags: 13.04, google-earth

running from terminal it shows the following

```
:~$ google-earth 
[0517/191140:ERROR:net_util.cc(2195)] Not implemented reached in bool
net::HaveOnlyLoopbackAddresses()
[0517/191145:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0517/191146:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
Google Earth has caught signal 11.
```

i am using Ubuntu 13.04 64bit version.

the crash log show this

```
Major Version 7
Minor Version 1
Build Number 0001
Build Date Apr 19 2013
Build Time 19:38:48
OS Type 3
OS Major Version 3
OS Minor Version 8
OS Build Version 0
OS Patch Version 0
Crash Signal 11
Crash Time 1368796311
Up Time 19.4486

Stacktrace from glibc:
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x23876c)[0x7f7150f7b76c]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x2389cd)[0x7f7150f7b9cd]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfbd0)[0x7f7151c49bd0]
./libbase.so(_ZN5earth15GfxCardInfoUnix25GetGraphicsCardMemoryInMBERi+0xe)[0x7f714b1e86fe]
/opt/google/earth/free/libevll.so(_ZN5earth4evll13VisualContext26DetectHardwareCapabilitiesEv+0x450)[0x7f713ed6a490]
/opt/google/earth/free/libevll.so(_ZN5earth4evll13VisualContext11OpenContextEN3Gap3Gfx25igRenderDestinationFormatERKNS0_8InitInfoE+0x1f4)[0x7f713ed6a8d4]
/opt/google/earth/free/libevll.so(_ZN5earth4evll13VisualContext4initERKNS0_8InitInfoE+0x123)[0x7f713ed6aa33]
/opt/google/earth/free/libevll.so(_ZN5earth4evll17RenderContextImpl4initERKNS0_8InitInfoE+0xeb)[0x7f713ec184db]
./librender.so(_ZN12RenderWidget6SetApiEPN5earth4evll3APIE+0x7a)[0x7f71486eda6a]
./librender.so(_ZN5earth6render12RenderWindow12createWidgetEv+0x17c)[0x7f71486dcd6c]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN5earth6client12ModuleWidget9showEventEP10QShowEvent+0x86)[0x7f7150f5bfc6]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget5eventEP6QEvent+0x599)[0x7f7150083299]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0xac)[0x7f715002c49c]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x20f)[0x7f715003473f]
./libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication14notifyInternalEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x8c)[0x7f714e35ca6c]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x12a)[0x7f71500852ca]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0xb1)[0x7f71500850e1]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7f71500851df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7f71500855da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7f7150085176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7f71500851df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0xb1)[0x7f71500850e1]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7f71500851df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7f71500855da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7f7150085176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7f71500851df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0xb1)[0x7f71500850e1]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7f71500851df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7f71500855da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7f7150085176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7f71500851df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7f71500855da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7f7150085176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7f71500851df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7f71500855da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7f7150085176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7f71500851df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7f71500855da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10showNormalEv+0x3d)[0x7f7150076c0d]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN10MainWindow18readScreensizeInfoEv+0xbc5)[0x7f7150f58855]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN5earth6client11Application12SetupMainWinENS0_3Kvw7ProductEb+0x323)[0x7f7151004c03]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN5earth6client11Application3runEv+0x700)[0x7f715100b6d0]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x238182)[0x7f7150f7b182]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(earthmain+0x1dc)[0x7f7150f7b38c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f715158eea5]
./googleearth-bin[0x4008b9]
```

Comment: For now, using windows version with wine seems to be the only solution.

Comment: The Google Earth package is in a very bad state and will probably not receive any maintenance updates, please try to use the WebGL browser version: https://www.google.com/maps/preview/?force=webgl

Answer (score 3):

1. Successfully installed GE 7, 32bit through GDebi Package Installer (GDPI). But it does not open.
2. Uninstalled GE 32 bit. Tried to install 64 bit. Did not get installed. Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: la32-libs
3. Installed GE 7 64bit, repackaged without 'la32-libs', through GDPI. Status: All dependencies are satisfied.
4. From GE icon, it opens for 1 or 2 seconds. Then it crashes. Same thing happens from terminal command also. No news so far about this bug, neither from Google nor Ubuntu.

---

### Latest steps to install GE7, 64bit on 14.04 LTS, which is fully working now.

I get scared to install anything remotely related to Windows! So I did not install WINE to even try Windows version of GE 7, 64 bit.

I could fix the crash-problem by following this method.

1. Install [GE 7 64bit](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3lYii-cLy3IWFh2Sm9oS2pHTFU/edit), repackaged without 'la32-libs', through GDPI. Status: All dependencies are satisfied.
2. Install : sudo apt-get install libfreeimage3
3. Download the file "[ge7.1.1.1580-0.x86_64-new-qt-
   libs-debian7-ubuntu12.tar.xz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3lYii-cLy3IYkpUSTZabTNQN2M/edit?usp=sharing)"
4. Untar the above file.

[image: qt lib]

5. Copy all files, except 'plugin' folder, and paste on to ' /opt/google/earth/free '. Inside the folder 'plugin', there is plugins/imageformats 
   folder containing 'libqgif.so' and 'libqjpeg.so' files. Copy these files and replace the existing files inside 'plugin' folder.

[image: qt lib2]

6. This is where the 'libqgif.so' and 'libqjpeg.so' files to be replaced.

[image: qt lib 3]

UPDATE May 07, 2014

Today I installed few updates through 'Software Updater'. I do not know what took place where, but to my amazement, now I find that all features of Google Earth 7, 64 bit are back and working. I can see all Panoramio and 360 degree pics. But the pixelised ocean is still there.

[image: Pixelised Ocean]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get past this by installing the 32 bit .deb instead of the 64 bit .deb. I still see the error when I launch from a terminal, the Google Earth launches and I have not had any problems with it so far.

Comment: I'm already on 32bit and still getting this.